# Update data into MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have written a PHP Script to insert data into MySQL, for client side i am using Android, by using first button i am uploading Image and by using second button I am storing Image Information into same table (Information like:- PersonName) i have around 10 fields.

but I am not getting my data in a same row, see below screen shot:-

[image]

I guess to store data in a same row, i need to use Update Query, but by Profession I am an Android Developer, so not strong in PHP, but i guess this is a small issue for any PHP Developer, please see my PHP Script below:

```
<?php
//*** Insert Record ***//
$objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$objDB = mysql_select_db("myDatabase");


/*** Check Username Exists ***/
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM image_information WHERE ImageName = '".$_FILES["filUpload"]["name"]."' ";
$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
$objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery);
if($objResult)
{
$arr['StatusID'] = "0";
$arr['Message'] = "File Name Exists";
echo json_encode($arr);
exit();
}

$strPersonName = $_POST["sPersonName"];

$strSQL = "INSERT INTO image_information";
$strSQL .="(ImageName, PersonName) VALUES ('".$_FILES["filUpload"]["name"]."','".$strPersonName."')";
$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filUpload"]["tmp_name"],"myfile/".$_FILES["filUpload"]["name"]))      
if(!$objQuery)
{
$arr['StatusID'] = "0";
$arr['Message'] = "Cannot upload Image(s)";
}
else
{
$arr['StatusID'] = "1";
$arr['Message'] = "Image(s) uploaded Successfully!";
}
mysql_close($objConnect);
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Comment: OMG. Some huuuge security holes, not talking about `mysql_*` functions. You know about [bobby tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) ?

Comment: Remember that `mysql` is deprecated, see the red box at: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php. Use `mysqli` or `pdo` instead.

Comment: Maybe the name of the file is in fact `IMG_20131128_005442.jpg',''),('`? ;) If you know what I mean

Comment: Abrahim are saying that above code runs twice firstly when you are uploading image and second when entering person name ?

Comment: I think SKV might be right about that.

Comment: "first button is for uploading and second button is for storing information into database - Abrahim Neil" i dont know your exact requirement but you can use one button for both task, you dont need a separate button for storing data into database. but if you are still looking for update solution for that you must have fileid so you update same record,  try this "UPDATE table_name SET col1=value-1, col2=value-2 WHERE FilesID = fileid"

Answer (score 1):

Abrahim,

As far as i understand your problem i found following.

First time you upload an image and your above said code is executed with query being :

```
"INSERT INTO image_information (ImageName, PersonName) VALUES ('filename.jpg','')" as currently the name is not entered.
```

Second time you enter person's name and the query executed this time is :

```
"INSERT INTO image_information (ImageName, PersonName) VALUES ('','person_name')" as image is not present now.
```

Now in order to avoid this you can do following

```
change you code as follows :

/*** Check Username Exists ***/
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM image_information WHERE ImageName = '".$_FILES["filUpload"]["name"]."' ";
$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
$objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery);
$strPersonName = $_POST["sPersonName"];
if($objResult)
{
    if($strPersonName!='') {
        $strSQL = "";
        $strSQL = "UPDATE image_information set PersonName = '$strPersonName' where FilesId = ".$objResult->FilesId;
        $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
        if(!$objQuery) {
            $arr['StatusID'] = "0";
            $arr['Message'] = "Cannot update person name";
        } else {
            $arr['StatusID'] = "1";
            $arr['Message'] = "Updated person name successfully.";
        }
    } else {
        $arr['StatusID'] = "0";
        $arr['Message'] = "File Name Exists";
        echo json_encode($arr);
    }
} else {

    $strSQL = "";
    $strSQL = "INSERT INTO image_information (ImageName, PersonName) VALUES ('".$_FILES["filUpload"]["name"]."','".$strPersonName."')";

    $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filUpload"]["tmp_name"],"myfile/".$_FILES["filUpload"]["name"]))
    if(!$objQuery)
    {
    $arr['StatusID'] = "0";
    $arr['Message'] = "Cannot upload Image(s)";
    }
    else
    {
    $arr['StatusID'] = "1";
    $arr['Message'] = "Image(s) uploaded Successfully!";
    }

}
mysql_close($objConnect);
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

I have not checked this you might need to tweak some part of it.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: `$arr['Message'] = "Cannot update person name;` check this line it should be `$arr['Message'] = "Cannot update person name";`

Comment: thanks for noticing PJ, thats a typo.. i already conveyed that this is not checked.

Answer (score 0):

add a space after the table name

```
$strSQL = "INSERT INTO image_information ";
$strSQL .="(ImageName, PersonName) VALUES ('".$_FILES["filUpload"["name"]."','".$strPersonName."')";
```

and be sure that your FilesID field is a primary key with auto increment mode on otherwise you should add it every time.

check also that an hardcoded version of you query is working properly before trying to fix your code. test this one:

```
$strSQL = "INSERT INTO image_information (ImageName, PersonName) VALUES ('A','B')";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
<?php
//*** Insert Record ***//
$objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$objDB = mysql_select_db("myDatabase");


/*** Check Username Exists ***/
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM image_information WHERE ImageName = '".$_FILES["filUpload"]["name"]."' ";
$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
$objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery);
if($objResult)
{
$arr['StatusID'] = "0";
$arr['Message'] = "File Name Exists";
echo json_encode($arr);
exit();
}

$strPersonName = $_POST["sPersonName"];
$strSQL = "";
$strSQL = "INSERT INTO image_information (ImageName, PersonName) VALUES ('".$_FILES["filUpload"]["name"]."','".$strPersonName."')";

$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filUpload"]["tmp_name"],"myfile/".$_FILES["filUpload"]["name"]))
if(!$objQuery)
{
$arr['StatusID'] = "0";
$arr['Message'] = "Cannot upload Image(s)";
}
else
{
$arr['StatusID'] = "1";
$arr['Message'] = "Image(s) uploaded Successfully!";
}
mysql_close($objConnect);
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Comment: I think i have to put Update query in PHP Script, your solution working for me like mine, just inserting data but still in different-different rows.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this will help u

```
   $strSQL = "INSERT INTO image_information (ImageName, PersonName) VALUES ('".$_FILES["filUpload"]["name"]."','".$strPersonName."')";

$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
```